# Regex to find special characters from a String with some exceptions

Tags: regex

I need to write a small regex which should match the occurrences of literal character * when it appears with any other special character. For example, I need to catch all of these occurrences `!* )* (* ** *.*` . The exception to this is `*=` and `=*`, which I want to allow. I tried writing the regex as

```
\W&&[^=]\*|\*\W&&[^=]
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions? Thanks much for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\*[^\w=]|[^\w=]\*)
```

That matches a asterisk followed by any non-word character (other than an equals sign), or a non-word character followed by an asterisk/

Answer (score 1):

That one matches all your *bad* samples:

```
(\!\*|\)\*|\(\*|\*\*|\*\.\*)
```

If you want more than these 4 cases, describe a bit better, what to allow and what to forbid.

Comment: Thanks Johannes for the response. But I was looking for a generic regex which works for any special character. It should catch all of the combination except *= and =*

Comment: Any occurrences of special characters which involve a * are to be caught. Only exception is *= and =*

Comment: anything which falls under \W 

Thanks.

Comment: ah ok, perl regex. Which library do you use? Perl itself?

Comment: I'm using this with Java pattern class

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
([^(\W\*)*(\*\W)*]|=\*|\*=)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for a regex with [lookbehind and lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Something like:

```
(?!=[\=\s])\*(?![\=\s])
```

Comment: The syntax for negative lookbehind is `(?<!`, not `(?!=`.